# Content Security Policy, how to add Hash Value dynamically for inline script

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2017, http-headers, content-security-policy

**Instead** of using **'unsafe-inline'** for script-src
want to use **sha256-base64Value**,
tried writing method creating hash value which is working fine.
But I'm not getting how to send **inline script** of particular page to that method .
If you have any other way to add hash value **dynamically**, you can tell me I'll try it.

### This is the code in Global.asax.cs

```
      protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
        {
            if (HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline)
            {
                Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
                Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
                Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
                Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
                Response.AddHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000");
                Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
                Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
                Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
                Response.Headers.Add("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer");
                Response.AppendHeader("Cache-control", "must-revalidate");
#if DEBUG
                string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
                string csp_hash = CreateSha256(url);
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Security-Policy", $"default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'");
#endif
            }
        }
```

And CreateSha256 method for Creating Hash value of particular string

```
private string CreateSha256(string script)
        {
            SHA256 hash = SHA256.Create();
            System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            byte[] byteValue = hash.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(script));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(byteValue);
        }
```

### If I remove unsafe-inline I'm getting error like

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' ". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Wz1Uxb0+2RcaDuihMSqqUC1Tat4XUDjiWRSS+V79Srw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I tried even sending current url to script-src, as I thought it will allow for that particular url but that also didn't work

If u need mpore details please inform
**Any help is fine**

Comment: First, I want to know what is used for hash value string 'csp_hash'. Second, which line causes the error you got?

Comment: 1. csp_hash is a dynamically generated hash value, if I pass particular script or url which generates same sha256- hash value as Chrome gives in console. I was trying to get same value as that , but I can choose different way(like hardcoding hash value given in console error) but I thought if Chrome is generating that value then I also can give a try.       2. I will get that error when I don't use 'unsafe-inline' keyword for Script-src

Comment: Did y you ever solve this?